# How to calculate SFV-style CRC32 in Linux commandline?

Tags: linux, command-line, crc32, command-line-tool

Is there an equivalent to md5sum/sha1sum in Linux for calculating SFV-style CRC32s?  I checked out cksum, but it seems to be calculating a different sum (perhaps a different polynomial? or I'm interpreting cksum's output wrong).  Preferably not using cfv/cksfv (both of which seem to be deprecated, and I would prefer not to download/compile a not-so-new tool every time I want to calculate this.

Also, would prefer not to do manual coding in C/C++/Java myself (i.e. would prefer not to implement the CRC32 personally), for the same reason as above.

If anyone knows exactly which CRC32 polynomial SFV uses (IEEE, Castagnoli, non-CRC Adler, etc.) that would be a great start as well.

Anyhow, many thanks in advance!

EDIT: seems not to be the adler, based on a Windows hashing tool that implements both Adler32 and something it only labels "CRC32".

Comment: Today I learnt: SFV = “Simple File Verification” file format.

Answer (score 5):

CheckSFV is a good open source tool and has a '-c' option to generate to stdout. But more importantly you can simply take the CRC32 calculation code if you are looking to use in C application (providing due licensing and credits are followed of course).

http://zakalwe.fi/~shd/foss/cksfv/

Hope this helps.